# QGroundControl Video Source issue

Tags: px4, qgroundcontrol

I'm dealing with a tricky problem on QGroundControl, it doesn't show video source options when I'm connected to the UAV, and I have no idea how to make this show up.
Already tried reinstalling with the recommendations, installing Qt Creator, but nothing worked.

On "Application Settings", in "General" under "Fly View", you should be able to see a "Video Source" option below the "Video decode priority". Or, like this example below, there is a "Video" submenu. Mine does show when I'm disconnected, but when I connect to Px4 on my Gazebo simulation, the video source disappears and it shows on the main page "Waiting for video".

[example image from https://docs.qgroundcontrol.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE1IT.png)

I have the same simulation running on a friend's computer and this option is showing.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Perhaps it has something to do with Ubuntu 16 version?